# Need assistance with Excel 2010 filtered cells query

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a summary sheet that details the amount of a certain product number found in a separate tab. The inventory tab has around 50k records that are filtered by certain manager names.

I need to search by the first four numbers on the inventory tab to match column `A` on the summary sheet.

Example:  The summary sheet may list the model type as `1234`, but the inventory sheet lists it as `123463AW3234`.

```
| Model | Codename | Marketing | Quantity |
|-------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 1234  | CN 1     | MN 1      | 1        |
| 1234  | CN 1     | MN 1      | 12       |
| 1234  | CN 1     | MN 1      | 13       |
```

I would add a formula into column `D` cells (quantity) that takes the text from cells within column `A` (model type) searches that through the inventory tab, and lists the quantity of that model type.

This is the formula I have so far, but it detects all cells with `1234` anywhere in the test.  I need to edit it where it will only search for the first four numbers taken from column `A`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET('Development-Asset list'!G2:G33080,ROW('Development-Asset list'!G2:G33080)-MIN(ROW('Development-Asset list'!G2:G33080)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B5,'Development-Asset list'!G2:G33080))+0)
```

Column `G` is a seperate tab and contains the full 10 digit product number. I want to pull the data from the model cell (`A1`) and use it to count the number of products in the sep tab `G` row.
These rows are filtered which is why I am using `SUMPRODUCT`. So column `G` has product numbers like `1234abcde` and I want to pull data from `A1` (`1234`) and search column `G` for matches, but only the first four characters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you give us a proper presentation of the sheets and column references, a screenshot will do. what is column G refering to? what are the sheet names? what do you have in the sheets? in which cells do you data sit in each sheet?

Comment: I was going to add a screenshot but it said my rep was too low hehe.  Column G is a seperate tab and contains the full 10 digit product number.  I want to pull the data from the model cell (A1) and use it to count the number of products in the sep tab G row.

Comment: These rows are filtered which is why I am using sumproduct.  So column G has product numbers like 1234abcde and I want to pull data from A1 (1234) and search column g for matches, but only the first four characters.  If that makes sense...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74705/excel-2010-filtered-cells-query join me in this chat room to send me the snapshot and more details, so i will update your question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=SumIfS(ColumnToSum, ColumnToSearch, Left(A2,4))
```

Check out the Sumifs function that allows you to set multiple search criteria. Notice that the item I searched for in the third argument is the left 4 characters of the search cell.

Answer (score 1):

how about a simple solution like this:

```
=SUMIF($G$2:$G$999;A2&"*";$H$2:$H$999)
```

it sums up the data in column H, if G starts with the four digits of A.